# Grid column filter not working with renderer in magento custom module

Tags: php, magento, filter, grid, adminhtml

I'm working with custom module for the magento backend, in this filter not working when using filter calback! Thanks!

I have tried some codes like this,

**Grid.php**

```
protected function _prepareCollection() 
    {        
     $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

     $this->setCollection($collection);

     return parent::_prepareCollection();        
    }

protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
        'width' => '50px',
        'type' => 'number',
        'index' => 'entity_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
        'index' => 'name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
        'width' => '120px',
        'index' => 'sku',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('packet_associate', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Packets Associated'),
        'width'     => '80px',
        //'index'     => 'packet_associate',
        'filter_index' => 'packet_associate',
        'renderer'  => 'stockmanagement/adminhtml_productassociate_renderer_associatestatus',
        'type'      => 'options',
        'options'   => array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'),
        'filter_condition_callback'
                    => array($this, '_filterPacketAssociateCondition'),
    ));

    $this->addColumn('action', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
        'width' => '200px',
        'type' => 'action',
        'getter' => 'getId',
        'actions' => array(
            array(
                'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Associate / Edit Packets'),
                'url' => array(
                    'base' => '*/*/new',
                    'params' => array('store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                ),
                'field' => 'id'
            )
        ),
        'filter' => false,
        'sortable' => false,
        'index' => 'stores',
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

**callback function**

```
protected function _filterPacketAssociateCondition($collection, $column) {
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('custom_table AS b', 'e.entity_id = b.product_id', 
            array('packet_associate' => 'COUNT(b.id)')); 
    $collection->getSelect()->group(entity_id);

    $collection->getSelect()->having(
            "packet_associate = ?"
            , $value);

    return $collection;
    //var_dump($collection->getSelect()->__toString());die();

}
```

**Associatestatus.php**

```
class   Module_Block_Adminhtml_Productassociate_Renderer_Associatestatus     extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{    
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{        
    $collection = Mage::getModel("stockmanagement/productassociate")->load($row->getId(), 'product_id')->getData();
    $resultCount = count($collection);
    if($resultCount > 0){
        echo 'Yes';
    }else{
        echo 'No';
    }
}
```

}

In this, Renderer working fine., only filter callback function is not working!!!

When i print the query in callback function like below, it gives correct result.

```
SELECT `e`.*, COUNT(b.id) AS `packet_associate` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `custom_table` AS `b` ON e.entity_id = b.product_id GROUP BY `entity_id` HAVING (packet_associate = '1')
```

But after applying filter it gives an error. Please suggest me anything.Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the thrown error by applying filters?

Comment: Sure. Here is the error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'packet_associate' in 'having clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` HAVING (packet_associate = '1')

Comment: Actually, the error thrown query and query printed in call back function both are different.

Comment: The query in your error, isn't the same the one you expect.
In your Error : 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM catalog_product_entity AS e HAVING (packet_associate = '1') '
The one you expect : 'SELECT `e`.*, COUNT(b.id) AS `packet_associate` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `custom_table` AS `b` ON e.entity_id = b.product_id GROUP BY `entity_id` HAVING (packet_associate = '1')'

Comment: Yes, I am not getting why it is happing.

Answer (score 0):

*Comments are limited, so I put this in Answer box.*

**Try to set**

```
protected function _filterPacketAssociateCondition($collection, $column) {
if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
    return $this;
}

$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->joinLeft('custom_table AS b', 'e.entity_id = b.product_id', 
        array('packet_associate' => 'COUNT(b.id)')); 
$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->group(entity_id);

$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->having(
        "packet_associate = ?"
        , $value);

    return $this;
}
```

**Instead of :**

```
protected function _filterPacketAssociateCondition($collection, $column) {
if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
    return $this;
}

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('custom_table AS b', 'e.entity_id = b.product_id', 
        array('packet_associate' => 'COUNT(b.id)')); 
$collection->getSelect()->group(entity_id);

$collection->getSelect()->having(
        "packet_associate = ?"
        , $value);

    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter products that have/haven't corresponded records in the `custom_table`.
In that case it's not necessary to group your results - it's a bit heavy operation, let's try to avoid it. Your callback function should look like this one:

```
protected function _filterPacketAssociateCondition($collection, $column)
{
    $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('b' => 'custom_table'), 'e.entity_id = b.product_id',
        array('product_id'));

    if ($value > 0) {
        $collection->getSelect()->where("b.product_id IS NOT NULL");
    } else {
        $collection->getSelect()->where("b.product_id IS NULL");
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, on the left join you will have an integer value in case the joined `product_id` column if current product has at least one corresponded row in the `custom_table`, otherwise you will have `NULL` in this column.